# Why I have the errors: Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Webkit (Safari 5+, Chrome) etc

Tags: css

I have that code and the errors: ,,Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome)" and ,,Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome)".

```
 .btn {
      background: #11CDD4;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD3, #11999E);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      -webkit-border-radius: 8;
      -moz-border-radius: 8;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      background: #30E3CB;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: What is presenting those errors? Why are you trying to support browsers that nobody uses any more with experimental features never intended for production?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some CSS properties, try this

```
.btn:hover {
    background: #11CDD3;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #11CDD3), color-stop(1, #11999E) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #11CDD3 5%, #11999E 100% );
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( center top, #11CDD3 5%, #11999E 100% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( center top, #11CDD3 5%, #11999E 100% );
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( center top, #11CDD3 5%, #11999E 100% );
    -webkit-border-radius: 8;
      -moz-border-radius: 8;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #30E3CB;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #30E3CB), color-stop(1, #2BC4AD) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #30E3CB 5%, #2BC4AD 100% );
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( center top, #30E3CB 5%, #2BC4AD 100% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( center top, #30E3CB 5%, #2BC4AD 100% );
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( center top, #30E3CB 5%, #2BC4AD 100% );
}
```

hope it will help  !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) to find out what prefixes you need to put before each of the CSS properties you are setting for each older browser (hover over the browser version).

`text-decoration` and `border-radius` are two that I have found in addition to what you have, but you need to check them all if you have to support the older browsers.